# Given an object of classes, how to type the object of initialized class instances in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const classMap = {service1: Service1, service2: Service2}
```

Where Service1 and Service2 are reference to classes, there can be a few hundreds classes.

Now I have an object that is dynamically created, which corresponds to this:

```
const instanceMap = {service1: new classMap.service1(), service2: new classMap.service2()}
```

And I want to type this instanceMap (type deduction failed here because the object is dynamically created).

The naive approach of "typeof classMap" doesn't work. When I use instanceMap.service1, I don't see the methods of Service1 classes in auto-complete. It seems the typeof operator is doing a typeof ServiceX, which erases all the methods of ServiceX class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `classMap`, where you apply [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) to each property value:

```
const classMap = { service1: Service1, service2: Service2 };
type ClassMap = typeof classMap;
type InstanceMap = { [K in keyof ClassMap]: InstanceType<ClassMap[K]> };
```

This is equivalent to

```
/* type InstanceMap = {
    service1: Service1;
    service2: Service2;
} */
```

And therefore you can [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `instanceMap` with that type without error:

```
const instanceMap: InstanceMap = {
    service1: new classMap.service1(),
    service2: new classMap.service2()
}; // okay
```

---

Now, if you want to make `instanceMap` dynamically, then you will also need mapped types in your function, and make liberal use of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation, as the compiler isn't smart enough to follow the logic.  For example:

```
function makeInstanceMap<T extends Record<keyof T, object>>(
    classMap: { [K in keyof T]: new () => T[K] }): T {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(classMap).map(([k, v]) => [k, new (v as any)()])
    ) as T;
}

const instanceMap = makeInstanceMap(classMap);
/* const instanceMap: {
    service1: Service1;
    service2: Service2;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PAjNA3gWAChpjoxoBeaTQgX0NEhgRXXgCZdCToAjC6AEQAvAbUL0A9gDsIAF2gMoAWTAAHfjmgQkaDJgBccHa0wAaLcYxtDzXe2g0A3IVkBPVfGgBhcMrX83DwkAMwVfCBVVZwJAzwBJGVkwKQxIjWgAbQBpaFQpaABreFcQ73DIgF1DBLlkjAAVd3gAHh9GSOyKgD4HQgB6ACpoWOgapJT4NMp8IhJtFj0bSyxo7nm7ayMF9miaaAG+8QJgaTlcxLrJtWqLianOWeJ1k0MpeAB3MPa1ADpnvQAFABKUxcObLTZvT6KCK-f7sYG0RzQPp9aASApgVxHQjBACuKVkqGk0AAtmAimNLpFmvVoPAAB6yeBSAAmMAASvATohWc0iiVQvVzBIeAArbmyLpdAFg4gwyKGTTZc6FYqlepVaBQ6DAig9eqdBxAwx0mbcRDwWR4xD5ADy4slP2CiAkpIAolJZIhUPAILLHtxoA6JcBZD8Wd7ff6FWogT9yaoAQCMgVzMgKkD9Zk09qPrrkKQYMlXEDgZm5dAs5BoPVdkcTolzrU7moOJRyZTbqk1ADY6ogdFBgpTvI8i2e6pNubwdsDFs7JhVrONkttmxdvtDgQgA)